# Ruby SQL Result to Grouped Hash

Tags: sql, arrays, json, ruby

I am Fetching Data from a proprietary Database (Sybase Advantage ADS)
Through a self written API that utilizes PHP and return the Results as JSON

so i have a Result that looks like this

```
[   
  {"year"=>"2016", "month"=>"1", "total"=>"1223"},  
  {"year"=>"2016", "month"=>"2", "total"=>"613"},   
  {"year"=>"2016", "month"=>"3", "total"=>"12351"},  
  {"year"=>"2017", "month"=>"1", "total"=>"123123"},   
  {"year"=>"2017", "month"=>"2", "total"=>"613123"},
  {"year"=>"2017", "month"=>"3", "total"=>"123"}
]
```

This is what i retrieve in Ruby, now in Order to work with the Date i'd like to create a Hash like this :

```
[  
  {:name => "2017", :data => {"1" => 123123, "2" => 613123, "3" => 123}},  
  {:name => "2016", :data => {"1" => 1223, "2" => 613, "3" => 12351}}  
]
```

This big array is ment to be split and merged by the year key, with each combination of month and total in it.

Furthermore i want to utilize the value of month as the key for total.

Any little help to get me started would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to start out using Ruby's `#group_by` method, which will group the rows by year, with the years as the keys and arrays of matching rows as the values:

```
>> groups = result.group_by { |row| row['year'] }
=> {"2016"=>
  [{"year"=>"2016", "month"=>"1", "total"=>"1223"},
   {"year"=>"2016", "month"=>"2", "total"=>"613"},
   {"year"=>"2016", "month"=>"3", "total"=>"12351"}],
 "2017"=>
  [{"year"=>"2017", "month"=>"1", "total"=>"123123"},
   {"year"=>"2017", "month"=>"2", "total"=>"613123"},
   {"year"=>"2017", "month"=>"3", "total"=>"123"}]}
```

Next you'll use `#map` to transform your data:

```
>> grouped_rows = groups.map { |year, values| {name: year, data: values.map { |value| [value['month'], value['total']] }.to_h} }
=> [{:name=>"2016", :data=>{"1"=>"1223", "2"=>"613", "3"=>"12351"}},
 {:name=>"2017", :data=>{"1"=>"123123", "2"=>"613123", "3"=>"123"}}]
```

If you want the rows sorted as shown, you can finish by calling `#sort_by` on the result:

```
>> grouped_rows.sort_by { |row| -row[:name].to_i }
=> [{:name=>"2017", :data=>{"1"=>"123123", "2"=>"613123", "3"=>"123"}},
 {:name=>"2016", :data=>{"1"=>"1223", "2"=>"613", "3"=>"12351"}}]
```